# Testing Mac App Subscription with Sandbox Account - Incorrect Date Issue

Tags: xcode, macos, in-app-purchase, sandbox, subscription

I found one strange issue when I am testing my Mac App with Sandbox account. My Mac app provides monthly subscription with 3-days free trial (Introductory Offer).

This is the dialog box for user ***eligible*** for 3 days trial, today is Nov 18, 2020. It shows Nov 21, 2020, this is correct, since this is 3 days after 18 Nov:

[image]

This is the dialog box for users ***ineligible*** for 3 days trial, when he want to subscribe Monthly plan, the dialog show starting Nov 21, 2020, but today is Nov 18, 2020. Why is it incorrect? It should show Nov 18, 2020:

[image]